# How to pass return value of a bean to other using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have a spring bean as follows

```
package com.test;

@Component
public class Sample{

  @Value("${url}")
  private String url = null;

  public String getURL(){
    return "test"+url;
  }
}
```

I have another bean in my `context.xml` file, which consumes url from above bean

```
 <bean id="build" class="com.test.Consumer">
    <property name="url" value="#{new com.test.Sample().getPassword()}"/>
</bean>
```

But it fails with error below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Expression parsing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Is this correct: `value="#{new com.test.Sample().getURL()}"` ?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be like this:

```
#{sample.url}
```

Where `sample` is the name of the `Sample` bean (default name is a name of the class with the first letter converted to lower case) and `url` is the name of the property you want to get from that bean.
You can check this link for more details: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef

Comment: Thanks when i used  #{sample.getURL()} i got error below                  
  Field or property 'sample' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'

Comment: Could you please add `context.xml` to the question?

Comment: And please try with property name not method name `#{sample.url}`

Comment: Got error below - "Field or property 'sample' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'"

Comment: Is package `com.test` included into package-scan in your context.xml?

Comment: hi Ivan, yes it is